# App Engine continues program execution despite throwing BadRequestException

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an App Engine application (Java) that 2 Android devices connect to. The App Engine backend provides a function 'setUsername' that allows clients to set their username.

```
public void setUsername(@Named("username") String username, User oauthUser) throws OAuthRequestException, BadRequestException {
    UserRecord user = OAuthTools.getUser(oauthUser);
    updateUsername(user, username);
    ofy().save().entity(user);
}

private void updateUsername(UserRecord user, String username) throws BadRequestException {
    user.name = username;
//Search for a user that already has the desired username. Note that the entity is NOT being saved in this method.
    UserRecord existingUser = ofy().load().type(UserRecord.class).filter("normalizedName", user.normalizedName).first().now();
    if(existingUser != null && existingUser.id != user.id) throw new BadRequestException("username taken");
}
```

The problem is as follows:
After I set some username with the first Android client by calling setUsername (for example, 'aaaa'), I try to set the same username using the second Android client (not simultaneously, at least 10 seconds have passed between calls). The backend then correctly throws a BadRequestException with the message "username taken", but it still writes the identical username to the second user in the database, i.e. both users have the username 'aaaa' set after this call from the second client.

Why does this happen? It is my understanding that the code execution should have stopped when throwing the Exception and therefore the ofy().save() call should never have been called.

The problem occurs with both the local app engine development server as well as when the backend application is deployed to the Google servers.

**Edit: The Problem seems to be that objectify saves the UserRecord created in updateUsername to the database although ofy().save() is never being called. Why is that?**

Answer (score 0):

You may have several other problems, but the root issue is that:

1. You need to use a transaction
2. You can't use regular queries inside of transactions

If you want to enforce uniqueness of usernames, you need to create a separate Username entity whose id is the username itself and load/create the Username along with the User record. Because your load of Username will be by primary key, you can transactionally guarantee its uniqueness.